# User mailbox looks empty in Outlook, but Get-MailboxStatistics shows data

Tags: exchange, outlook

Friends,

I'm looking at an issue where a user has stuff in his mailbox according to Exchange, but nothing shows up in his Outlook nor in his OWA. We're using Exchange Server 2016 and recently updated to CU6. The user is running Outlook 2013. I've seen [this link](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/rmilne/2017/06/27/exchange-2016-cu6-released/) where it talks about CU6 breaking OWA, but it's not the same issue because nothing is showing in either Outlook or OWA. I've had him rebuild his profile as well. Any ideas?

Edit: I moved his mailbox to a different database and now he sees mail that has been sent to him since the move, but nothing prior to that. I gave myself full control to the box and I see mail back to the 23rd of this month, which appears to be the correct amount of mail. I had the user check to see if his view settings were different and had him reset his current views.

Answer (score 0):

OWA will show you the true nature of the mailbox. If you have reset the views, then the content should be seen. The move mailbox trick usually resolves issues with the mailbox. You could also try a repair of the mailbox.

You haven't said how you are checking that content exists - there a number of ways, and not all content in a mailbox is visible to users. get-mailboxfolder is what I would use, as it allows you to see the item count per folder.

Comment: No idea why, but it's good now without any other actions by me. Sorry to whoever else runs into this post.

Thanks for the answer Sembee, but I did mention that I can see all the content when I take full control of his box, as well as mentioning that I did run Get-MailboxStatistics to see that he indeed had stuff in there.